# What type(s) of analysis should be performed on a discrete voltage regulator circuit?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, differential-amplifier

I am tasked with building a fully discrete voltage regulator. I am restricted to only using discrete components, such as transistors, diodes, resistors etc., no ICs are allowed.

Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT4WO0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In know of ac small signal analysis and DC analysis, but I am left to wonder how am I supposed to analyze a circuit that is designed to work even when fed by a varying voltage source with large voltage ripple or variations.

Ac small signal won't help me above say 10-15 mV and DC analysis is useful only for determining the biasing of the circuit.

**How should I analyze a circuit like the one in the schematic above?**

Comment: Use a simulation package. They are free, do a better job than any other method and, are what everyone uses these days if you are serious about EE.

Comment: The data sheet of a linear IC regulator should show specifications that the manufacturer regards important to its performance. You might consider these specs when evaluating your design.

Comment: You need DC analysis first (complicated by the variable output), then AC analysis, and followed by TRAN analysis. You must add a variable "load" (known) to be complete ...

Comment: @Antonio51 My problem is that AC analysis and AC small signal models in the way I understand them function for significantly lower ripple/ variations.

Comment: @glen_geek That 's a good idea. I will look into it.

Comment: @Andyaka I am aware of the abundance of free simulation software. I cannot explain to my professors that the circuit I built functions because the simulator says so. I am merely looking for a way I guess of making sense of input voltage variations that are not slow enough to be DC, but also too big to be considered small AC signals.

Comment: I use simulators to demonstrate to customers (who pay good money) how a circuit functions so, unless you are told that you can't use simulation software, I fail to see the problem.

Comment: According to my profs. The circuit analysis (as in manual circuit analysis , extrapolating the differential amplification, CMRR etc.) should come before simulating the circuit and essentially confirming that the thinking is correct.

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs Your profs are correct to tell you that. Simulation should only be used to validate a soundly reasoned design ***after*** that design is performed. What's missing from what you provided us is that reasoning. I see what amounts to a vague behavioral sketch. But nothing quantitative, at all. Can you add your thoughts and also any design criteria you've had imposed on you or that you've imposed upon yourself?

Comment: @periblepsis Thank you for your comments, I've discussed with my profs about some of my doubts and I now have a somewhat better understanding of what they expect me to analyze and obtain. I don't think there is any point to keep this question around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110). This [file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/q6pv1ahj9woarizrlv09h/alim-stabilisee-classique-v001.cir?rlkey=v8z30ra1y8mr7iytnd0990n1y&dl=0) to download.

Choose Vcc = 15 V for example (must be enough for obtaining voltage output).
When starting, choose I2 enough to "polarize" the zener (5 V) correctly (say 5 mA).
I2 can be also a resistor R10, value 2 kOhm ( \$(15-5)/5 mA \$).
Q1 and Q2 are working as a "differential" amplifier.
I1 should be a resistor R1 = 1 kOhm (current ~ 4 mA).
R4 should be something like 5 kOhm.
R6 = 1 kOhm, R5 = 10 kOhm, pot = 1 kOhm.
Then, try to obtain DC characteristics, which would be ...

[image]

For your needs ... 9 V output, changed the resistors in green.

[image]

And here is "how" (output characteristic) I measured the DC internal impedance.

[image]

Here is the AC Analysis (variables C1 and I1 ).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for simulating the circuit, it's definitely helpful seeing it working.

Comment: It is only the "start" ... Other "things" must occur. For that, you need more "specifications".

Comment: The specifications I was given are somewhat vague and not really fixed targets. It is supposed to drop the voltage from 12-15V to 9V and have an output impedance of 1000 ohms, the open-loop amplification should be at least 100.

Comment: In this case, adjust my R6 to increase the output voltage. With the simulator, it is easy to do that. Just click the ".define a 0.5" and click on the arrows up or down (0 < a < 1).

Comment: I see, and in the circuit you simulated what would the output resistance be ?

Comment: I see that you've modified the schematic to better match my need, for which I am of course thankful. I understand modifying R5 and R6 to change the amount of sampled voltage, but what is the role of R9 in the circuit? Is it just a test load or a way to tweak the output impedance?

Comment: You must plot the output voltage versus the current into the load. You can do it with the simulator (at least 2 methods)

Comment: Changed R4 (currents = through Q1 and Q2) and R6 to adjust the output voltage.  Just a test load for R9.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

A regulator must tolerate a specified range of input voltage, and
of output loads.   DC analysis of a few points in those ranges
is appropriate.

As for AC, there's a bit of feedthrough in most regulators; none
are commonly useful without an output filter capacitor,
which (with its small series resistance) can be analyzed by
observing the output with an AC component added to Vcc.

A transient analysis for abrupt turn-on, and for turn-off,
is also useful (the turn-off case for high values  of output
capacitance was found to be destructive in the old uA78xx
regulators).

Comment: Point taken in using an output filter capacitor. I don't know if I will be able to include a more complex filtering sub circuit or preregular, but I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

As well as DC and low-frequency characteristics such as load and line regulation and mains-frequency related rejection you should do analyis relating to stability and overshoot/undershoot with almost-instant load current (and line voltage) changes.

The latter will be affected by input and output impedances (output capacitor and load current), so you need to include more components than are shown in your schematic.

Comment: I will keep in mind your advice when designing the circuit. I think stability analysis is a tad too complex for pen and paper and I would probably defer to the output of a simulator.